# Who reviews edits during closed beta?

Tags: support, editing

I'm wondering who is doing the edit approvals during the closed beta? Robert and Rebecca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that [privileges](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/privileges) have essentially the same structure as on "grown-up" sites (like [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges)), but each requires less reputation.
Therefore, everybody with [edit privilege](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) should be able to approve edits. And everybody with access to [moderator tools](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) can see [suggested edits page](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits).

But since we don't have any 500 rep users yet, you're probably right: mods will do that for now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I can see that will kick in tomorrow with some users reaching 500 tomorrow.